# How does OpenWPMs run_custom_function affect the Scope?

Tags: python, scope

I'm trying to scrape some sites with [OpenWPM](https://github.com/mozilla/OpenWPM) and wrote a custom function `get_pp_links()`, that adds something to a global list. But when I use it with OpenWPMs 
[`run_custom_function()`](https://github.com/mozilla/OpenWPM/wiki/Available-Commands#run_custom_function), the things I append to the list disappear.

My script looks like this:

```
from automation import CommandSequence, TaskManager

NUM_BROWSERS = 2
alist = [1]

def get_pp_links(**kwargs):
    alist.append(1)

def main():
    # The list of sites that we wish to crawl
    with open("top-100.csv", "r") as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        sites = list(csv_reader)

    # Loads the default manager preferences
    manager_params, browser_params = TaskManager.load_default_params(NUM_BROWSERS)

    # Update browser configuration
    for i in range(NUM_BROWSERS):
        browser_params[i]['headless'] = True

    # Instantiates the measurement platform
    manager = TaskManager.TaskManager(manager_params, browser_params)

    for site in sites:
        command_sequence = CommandSequence.CommandSequence("https://"+site[1], reset=True)
        command_sequence.get(sleep=0, timeout=60)
        command_sequence.run_custom_function(get_pp_links, ())
        manager.execute_command_sequence(command_sequence)

    # Shuts down the browsers and waits for the data to finish logging
    manager.close()
    print(alist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And `top-100.cvs` contains a domain list:

```
92,twitch.tv
93,forbes.com
94,bbc.com
```

I'm expecting the list to grow with every scanned site, so the result would look like `[1,1,1,1]`, but instead, the printed list is only `[1]`

I think this is somehow connected to the `run_custom_function()`, because when I call `get_pp_links()` directly, the problem does not appear.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `get_pp_links` function gets called at all?

Comment: It does. If I add an `print(alist)` at its end, I get 3 time `[1,1]` printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because OpenWPM creates a new process for each browser spawned.

Since each process is isolated against the parent process and each other the following happens.

1. `alist` gets created in the main process.
2. `alist` gets copied into the browser process.
3. `alist`  gets changed by `get_pp_links` in the browser process
4. The changes stay in the browser process and you can't observe them in the parent process.

You might be able to get around this by using a [`multiprocessing.SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) and syncing the list between the processes.